# time series data in mongodb - how to query embedded document

Tags: mongodb, time-series

I'm working on a design for a time series dataset, basically I have servers I monitor, and I would like to know some metric about it over a period of time. 
based on http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb 
I created a design that is a document per server+month, and in it an embedded document per day, in it an embedded document per hour, and in it the metrics.

so inserting the data for two hours for a certain server looks like this :

**-- for server i-09484d47 and date 2015/02/23 hour 16**

```js
db.servers.update(
  { _id : "i-09484d47_201502",
    service: "AWS/EC2",
    owner : "gil"
  }, 
  {$set: {"values.23.16.samples": 60 ,"values.23.16.average": 0.33883, "values.23.16.minimum": 0.16, "values.23.16.maximum": 0.67} },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

**-- for server i-09484d47 and date 2015/02/23 hour 17**

```js
db.servers.update(
  { _id : "i-09484d47_201502",
    service: "AWS/EC2",
    owner : "gil"
  }, 
  {$set: {"values.23.17.samples": 60 ,"values.23.17.average": 0.6, "values.23.17.minimum": 0.5, "values.23.17.maximum": 0.8} },
  { upsert: true }
)
```

and so on.

now i would like to get all the data for a specific server, for a given date range, say a certain week (let's say its contained within a single month). 
i don't want to pull the entire document and do the filtering on the client.
any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you save the updated date in your document and use it to query your db?

Comment: didn't understand your question, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are specifying the time and date in the keys, you can do this by projecting the keys you want displayed. So if you wanted the week from 16 to 22 February, you could do something like this:

```js
db.servers.find(
    { "_id": "i-09484d47_201502" },
    {
        "values.16": 1,
        "values.17": 1,
        "values.18": 1,
        "values.19": 1,
        "values.20": 1,
        "values.21": 1,
        "values.22": 1
    }
);
```

You can see how this is a pain to type out manually, so you might want to use a function that returns the projection object given a range of dates. Within the same month, in JavaScript, it would work something like this:

```js
function generateProjection(start, end) {

    obj = {};
    prefix = "values";

    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        var key = prefix + "." + i;
        obj[key] = 1;
    }

    return obj;
}
```

Which you could then use as follows:

```js
var proj = generateProjection(16, 22);
db.servers.find({ "_id": "i-09484d47_201502" }, proj);
```

With a little variation, you can add support for multiple months and hours, if you wish. The alternative would be to alter your schema so that the information about the date is contained as a value, and perhaps store each subdocument in an array, so that you can take advantage of the `$unwind` operator in `aggregation`.

PS. A little off topic, but given that `_id` is unique, you don't need to specify all of that match criteria in your update query. You can simplify it to something like the following:

**EDIT:**
Added `$setOnInsert` clause to cover fields required for `upsert`.

```js
db.servers.update(
  { "_id": "i-09484d47_201502" }, 
  { "$set": { ... },
  { "$setOnInsert": { "service": "AWS/EC2", "owner": "gil" } },
  { "upsert": true }
);
```

Comment: I think the point point of the additional fields in there was because of the `upsert` action so they would be created in a new document. Modern releases should not actually "update" those fields if they are unchanged ( at least they would not report as modified under Bulk API methods ) but probably a better alternative for the intent is [**`$setOnInsert`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) which is intended to only be applied on document creation.

Comment: amazing! thank you very much for the detailed answer.

a few things : 
- how exactly do you mean to store the date as value ? its not already like this?
- regarding subdoc as array, if i need to access a certain day, how will i know which array cell contains it? not each document will contain all days (if for example the data started coming in the middle of the month), so i can't asssume there are always ~30 subdocs.

Comment: Glad it helped! I mean that if you look at the document as `{ key: value }` pairs, you are storing the information that tells you what date/time it is in the `key`, not the `value`. An alternative would be to have your `values` field as an array of ~30 days * 24 hours = 720 sub documents containing the current information (`samples`, `average`, etc.) plus `day` and `hour`. So then you can query that array using dot notation.

Comment: if i use arrays so that each hour will be a cell, how i do i add data to it, meaning i want to kinda do upsert - 
if the document does not exists - create it and create that one cell
if the document does exists but that array cell doesn't - create that array cell

note that i do not have to deal with updating an existing cell, its only inserts.